# iOS - How to create a never ending scrolling news feed

Tags: ios

I have to create a social app, which currently displays only 20 items in a user's news feed. Once they hit the bottom there is a "Load More button this will then extend the stable to the next 20 items.

Its very manual and not very fluid, is there a way to automate this?

The feature is something very similar to the likes of Facebook and Twitter, so I know it is  possible but my Googling is only taking me so far as I don't know the right terminology to use for this feature.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start fetching the next items once the user is near the end of the list.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger maximumNumberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    if (indexPath.row >= maximumNumberOfRows - kReloadOffset) {
        [self fetchNextItemsFromWebserviceWithOffset:maximumNumberOfRows];
    }
```

In `fetchNextItemsFromWebserviceWithOffset` you can fetch more news items and update your table view with `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: I am using indexPath.section instead of indexPath.row will the same code apply?

Comment: Depends on your data model, if you can determine by the current section that the user is near the end of the displayed items sure.

Comment: can you also update `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` on the fly (so the use can not scroll past the end of cells that haven't been loaded, yet?)

Comment: You should return the number of already loaded items in `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, not the number of total items. This way the user can't scroll past the end of the table. When `reloadData` is called the new items are loaded, therefore `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the correct number again.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data when you are near to end using this method or you can also use Mark Gibson's Code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height - screensizehere*2)
    {
        if (!isCalling)
        {
            isCalling = YES;// when you response data change this bool to NO.
            [self getdatainbg];//call your service.
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Table view. Load only 20 or whatever amount you require. When you get to the end of the scroll load another 2O. Its very basic and simple. Your cells will get reused again and again and its a never ending, till data is available.

Answer (score -1):

Make your UIViewController class to listen for UIScrollViewDelegate

```
@interface Yourclass : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

/*Your getters & setters, method declarations*/

@end

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate & refresh for auto scroll
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{    

    /*Auto scroll Code.. Raja implemented..*/

    if (([scrollView contentOffset].y + scrollView.frame.size.height) == [scrollView contentSize].height) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(refreshPage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        return;
    }
}
```